# How remove unnecessary Mockito stubbings error

Tags: spring-boot, junit

```
@Test
public void testWhenCorrectRequestPassedToUpdateCasaApplicationForIncomeUpdate() throws InvalidEventException {

    when(requestMapper.map(getApplicationUpdateRequestForIncome())).thenReturn(getCasaApplicationData());
    when(service.updateApplication(any())).thenReturn(getResultApplicationStatus());
    when(responseMapper.updateMap(any())).thenReturn(getUpdationResponse());

    Result<ApplicationUpdationResponse> response = casaApplicationHandler
            .updateCasaApplication(getApplicationUpdateRequestForIncome());

    assertNotNull(response);
    assertTrue(response.isSuccess());

}
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Unneccessary Stubbing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947613/how-to-resolve-unneccessary-stubbing-exception)

Comment: You can remove the particular stub